# Will RAID 0 array still work if I replace bad MOBO with identical model?

Tags: motherboard, data-recovery, raid-0

My motherboard, which is an Abit AA8XE recently failed. I had most of my data backed up but would like to recover the rest.  The problem is my drives where set up in RAID 0.  If I replace the bad motherboard with another AA8XE will my RAID 0 array still work? Are there any other issues I might encounter?

Answer (score 1):

If you create a hardware configuration identical to your original, your drives should work, provided they are not also damaged.

If your mobo failed during a disk write, you might have some missing or corrupted data.